# Query filter to display records in a date time frame

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

Good morning,
I have a table of usage statistics for an internet circuit that provides a 5 minute breakdown of usage for a month.
Example:

```
CODE
ID    Time                    InPct    OutPct    InMbps    OutMbps
285    2/1/2010 11:40:00 PM    0.066391    0.102875    0.00102    0.00158
286    2/1/2010 11:45:00 PM    0.090858    0.157753    0.001396    0.002423
287    2/1/2010 11:50:00 PM    0.064748    0.108285    0.000995    0.001663
288    2/1/2010 11:55:00 PM    0.062174    0.092498    0.000955    0.001421
289    2/2/2010 12:00:00 AM    0.348073    0.167378    0.005346    0.002571
290    2/2/2010 12:05:00 AM    0.230889    0.264634    0.003546    0.004065
291    2/2/2010 12:10:00 AM    0.094604    0.150474    0.001453    0.002311
292    2/2/2010 12:15:00 AM    0.140493    0.136141    0.002158    0.002091
293    2/2/2010 12:20:00 AM    0.092592    0.128323    0.001422    0.001971
294    2/2/2010 12:25:00 AM    0.190524    0.122717    0.002926    0.001885
295    2/2/2010 12:30:00 AM    0.074951    0.097418    0.001151    0.001496
```

What I would like to do is query usage statistics between 2/2/2010 2:30 PM to 2/3/2010 9:00 AM for each day ( the date is variable ). The date/time are stored in a single field. When attempting to specify a criteria of Between date()-1 #2:30:00 PM# and date() #9:00:00 AM#, no results are produced when running the query. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Do I need to split the time out to its own field?
Any help is most appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: Horrible question formatting by the way!! Look at ways to get the data tabulated.
Have you tried `Between Date() - 1 + #2:30:00 PM# And Date() + #09:00:00 AM#`

Comment: Thanks Skippy , values returned but how can the system return values for weekdays ( now the system only return values which meet the expression)

Comment: What do you mean? 2010-02-01 and -02 are both weekdays.

Comment: Yes exactly if 2010-02-01 and 2010-02-02 is weekdays ( Not working days) how the system will return these values in next working day :)

Comment: They are Monday and Tuesday according to the ISO calendar. To skip weekend dates see function added below.

Answer (score 0):

How to get the workday following (or preceding) a weekend for dates of that weekend:

```
Public Function DateSkipWeekend( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booReverse As Boolean) _
  As Date

' Purpose: Calculate first working day equal to or following/preceding datDate.
' Assumes: 5 or 6 working days per week. Weekend is (Saturday and) Sunday.
' Limitation: Does not count for public holidays.
'
' May be freely used and distributed.
' 1999-07-03, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, Copenhagen

  Const cintWorkdaysOfWeek As Integer = 5

  Dim bytSunday   As Byte
  Dim bytWeekday  As Byte

  bytSunday = Weekday(vbSunday, vbMonday)
  bytWeekday = Weekday(datDate, vbMonday)

  If bytWeekday > cintWorkdaysOfWeek Then
    ' Weekend.
    If booReverse = False Then
      ' Get following workday.
      datDate = DateAdd("d", 1 + bytSunday - bytWeekday, datDate)
    Else
      ' Get preceding workday.
      datDate = DateAdd("d", cintWorkdaysOfWeek - bytWeekday, datDate)
    End If
  End If

  DateSkipWeekend = datDate

End Function
```

In a query:

```
Select 
    ID,
    DateSkipWeekend([Time]) As Workday,
    InPct,
    OutPct,
    InMbps,
    OutMbps
From
    YourTable
Where
    [Time] Between 
        DateAdd("d", -1, Date()) + #2:30:00 PM# 
        And 
        Date() + #09:00:00 AM#
```

Comment: I don' mean that
e.g. If today date is 25/02/2017 ( Not working day) and need to return values from 22/01/2017 till 25/02/2017 on that day , what the expression which can be used to meet the criteria ?

Comment: Thanks Gustav , it is working fine in criteria but i want to implement it as below :
IIf(Weekday(Date())=1,[Time] Between DateAdd("d", -1, Date()) + #2:30:00 PM# And Date() + #09:00:00 AM# 
but it seems that there is an issue 'The expression you entered contains invalid syntax ' 
Could you please check and let me what exactly the issue in building the expression .

Comment: You miss the final part of the `IIf` statement. But it seems like you are about mixing up things.

Comment: what is the missing part ? I want to return the records which meet the expression from date to date in case weekday is Sunday

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. But look up the syntax on `IIf`.